# Create a copy of each new item to another list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, copy-item

I'm new in sharepoint, and Im using SharePoint on-premises 2013.
I created 3 lists (A, B, and C).
The user can add a new item in list A or B and I want to make a copy of each item that has been created in List C. So, list C will contains all items in A and B.

I used sharepoint designer 2013 and used (Create list item Action) and chose ( start workflow automatically when an item is created).
Items copied correctly but without attachments.

I need your help to find a way to add attachments to the other list after creating the item,  whether using sharepoint designer or programatically?

Thanks in advance!